# Getting different RSA encryption result in different language?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, rsa, sha512

I am trying to encypt some data using RSA public key and signing with SHA-512 algo. But response recevied is differnet in different plat
form.

In C#:

```
    RSACryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    crypto.ImportCspBlob(Convert.FromBase64String(publickey));
    crypto.exportParameters(false); // and got the public key modulus and exp
    byte[] response = crypto.SignData(data, "SHA512");
```

In Java:

```
    // got modulus and exp for public key from c# 
    byte[] modulo = {.....};         
    byte[] exp = {1,0,1};                
    BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, modulo);     
    BigInteger pubExp = new BigInteger(1, exp);     
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    RSAPublicKeySpec priKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, pubExp);
    RSAPublicKey Key = (RSAPublicKey)keyFactory.generatePublic(priKeySpec);

    // Calculate Hash
    MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    byte[] digest = sha1.digest(data);     
    // Encrypt digest
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key);
    byte[] response = cipher.doFinal(digest);
```

but both response are not matching.C# generate correct one but java not generating the same byte[]
Any missing part in java code.

Comment: There are different formats around. My guess is the outcome is semantically identically but not byte-ident because of the different formats used (java uses PKCS7 afaik)

Comment: If you want to sign data in Java use the [Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html) class.

Comment: @GregS And try to sign with the private key. Thoma, please show your actual code as two separate [MCVE's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Currently there is e.g. a spelling mistake in your C# code.

Comment: @GregS but using Signature class required Private Key. Then how to generate private key from exported paramas.??

Comment: You *sign* with the private key and *verify* with the public key. The Signature class supports that.

Answer (score 0):

private static final String algorithm = "AES/CBC/NOPadding";
if we convert type 中國傳統的 languages then we get null value when we encryt.To overcome this problem we use below thing.
 private static final String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
if we do diifferent type languages like 中國傳統的 converion can be encryted.